# Blender Eevee Keeps crashing when i try to render

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine

So I have this animation full of custom rigs that I animated in blender 2.79 and am trying to render in Eevee. When I hit the f12 key the frame renders out, but as soon as it's done blender closes.

I was wondering if anyone had any insight to what the problem might be and how to fix it.

Comment: Maby your computer just can't handle it, try lowering the resolution and other settings and see if it still crashes.

Comment: These are the stats of my cp AMD Ryzen 5 1600 Six-Core Processor with 12 threads
16 GBs of RAM
Radeon RX 580 with 8 GBs

Comment: This is also the same result for cycles render in blender 2.80 as well

Comment: Check out this video to find solution for your issue
https://youtu.be/3g2yiAQaWCE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of opening the 2.79 file in blender 2.80 i just appended the objects in my scene to the startup file for 2.80 and it rendering seems to be working so far now.